# PHP: getting session variable from included file

Tags: php, session, include, session-variables

I was wondering if there's an issue with this?

I'm including a file that has session variable, but I'm trying to get that session variable from the included file, but its not passing through?

index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
ob_start(); // Initiate the output buffer
include("file.php");
echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

file.php

```
$_SESSION['name'] = "Andrew";
```

my `index.php` file is not echoing anything.

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've added session_start in the beginning my `index.php`

Comment: And hopefully you have also forgotten to add `<?php` to the beginning of `file.php` which then brings me to the point that the code you posted here is very fine. Not the issue. Can we close your question now?

Comment: actually, i figured out my answer. I'd like to close it

Comment: @andrewliu: Add the answer below and accept it instead. Also the code you had posted, did just work for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/HLb9h8 - that's just what I meant.

Comment: It works, if you know the answer and if it's below then accept it plz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add

```
session_start();
```

at the beginning of the file

and add

```
<?php
```

to file.php

because without

```
<?php
```

file.php is read as html

Comment: Please see my updated, I've added that in the start already that I forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

every file you use the `SESSION` variable u must include this

```
session_start();
```

at the top

Comment: Please see my updated, I've added that in the start already that I forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

Create file bootstrap.php (or whatever name you choose) and include this file on every other in beginning. In bootstrap.php you will have two possible solutions:

1. `session_start();`
2. `ini_set('session.auto_start', 1);`

at the beginning of file. Also you can write this lines in your php.ini:

```
session.auto_start on
```

Try to **delete** `session_regenerate_id()`